# After ajax successful... how to recheck php if-else condition without refreshing page

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

when i click "add to cart" button... ajax successfully add product in database. and as a result he should recheck again php if-else condition. But it doesn't. However, after refreshing page, which cause reconnecting to db, information updating. Here is the php code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($products) && is_array($products) && count($products)){
$i=1;
foreach ($products as $data) { ?>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" ">
  <div class="tile">
   <img class="prod_image"  src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>../upload/<?php echo $data['image'] ?>">
     <div class="prod_detail">
         <p class="prod_name"><?php echo $data['name'] ?></p>
         <p class="prod_name"><?php echo $data['weight'] ?></p>
         <p class="prod_name"><?php echo $data['price'] ?></p>

         <?php                

         //if product already add in cart
         $isincart = get_product_from_cart($data['id']);

         if($isincart < 1) { ?>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addtocart(<?= $data['hid'];?>,<?= $data['weight'];?>,<?= $data['price'];?>)">Add to cart</button>


         <?php } if ($isincart > 0){

          ?>

         <div id="prod_quant" class="add_btn_sec">
             <form id="myform" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)">
                 <input type="submit" onclick="quantitydec(<?= $data['id']; ?>)" value="-" class="qtyminus" field="quantity<?= $data['id']; ?>">

                 <input type="text" id="quantity<?= $data['id']; ?>" name="quantity<?= $data['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo ($isincart) ; ?>" class="qty">

                 <input type="submit" onclick="quantityinc(<?= $data['id']; ?>" value="+" class="qtyplus" field="quantity<?= $data['id']; ?>">
            </form>
         </div>


        <?php 
          }
          ?>

     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php } $i++; } ?>
```

and ajax script is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function addtocart(p_id,p_weight,p_price)
    {   
          $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('index.php/addtocart/addtocart_ajax');?>",
                  data: {'id': id, 'name': name, 'p_wight': p_weight, 'p_price': p_price},
                  dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(response){                    
                        /*do something here*/ 
                    }
                });
    }

  </script>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to recheck " if($isincart < 1) " condition without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
**PHP** - is a server side language. PHP codes are interpreted at the server before the html file is sent to the browser. Please note that browser cannot interpret php codes.

Now **AJAX** - Ajax is a client-side script that communicates to and from a server/database without the need for a complete page refresh. The best definition I’ve read for Ajax is “the method of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page – without reloading the entire page.”

Now coming to your question, if you want to run a php code after the AJAX success, you would need to send another AJAX request as the success function of the first AJAX request.

Hope this makes sense.